# Ruby recursion return result issue

Tags: ruby

I have the next issue when am trying to use recursion.

Test Cases

```
puts exact_sum?(12, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) => true (he finds it true but returns false)


puts exact_sum?(11, [1, 5, 9, 13]) => false
```

The behavior of the function is what I am aiming to do but even if he finds true he always returns false.

```
def exact_sum?(k, coins, i = 0)
  if (k == 0) then 
    print "there is one true #{k}"
    return true
  elsif (i == coins.length)
    return false
  end
  number = coins[i]
  exact_sum?(k-number,coins, i + 1)
  exact_sum?(k,coins, i + 1)
end
```

Comment: _"I have the next issue [...]"_ – it this a follow-up question? If so, please provide a link to the previous one.

Comment: @Stefan: Some languages express "the following" and "the next" with the same expression - it's likely just a second language issue.

Comment: @Amadan good point!

Comment: Am not used to speak English as good as it should be I ll be mind that. :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning `true` or `false` in the base cases, but the recursive case is wrong. Ruby returns the returned value of the last statement in the method if it doesn't execute an explicit `return`. In this case the last statement is `exact_sum?(k,coins, i + 1)`. What I think you want is to return `true` if any of the recursive parts is true, which would be:

```
exact_sum?(k-number,coins, i + 1) || exact_sum?(k,coins, i + 1)
```